# Непрерывная работа MediaPlayer при смене Activity

Tags: java, android, activity, mediaplayer

Есть две активити, например А и В.
Когда при запуске приложения выполняется активити А, то в ней стартуется плеер.
При переходе в активити В плеер замалкивает, хотя не должен, то есть при смене активити плеер должен остаться играющим.
Я пробовал много вариантов, начиная с запоминания времени при переходе и начале воспроизведения начиная с него, и заканчивая сервисом. Есть ли какие-нибудь идеи по "незатыкающемуся" плееру?

**UPDATE** Код сервиса:

```
public class MenuMusicService extends Service {
private static final String TAG = null;
MediaPlayer player;

public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.main_menu_theme);
    player.setLooping(true); // Set looping
}

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    player.start();
    return 1;
}

public IBinder onUnBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
}
}
```

---

Запускаю сервис из активити с помощьюc
    `startService(new Intent(this, ru.zein4.rpm.utilities.MService.class));`

Comment: а вы часом сервис при переходе на следующею activity не убиваете ?

Comment: @gadfil Нет, не убиваю

Comment: Вообще это решается при помощи сервиса, а почему у вас этот вариант не заработал — без кода остаётся лишь гадать.

Comment: Сервис должен решить вашу проблему. Если не решает - вы что-то делаете неправильно. Приведите код сервиса.

Comment: Через логи посмотрл процесс запуска сервиса. Сам класс был запущен, но ни одного метода в нём вызвано не было. Почему?

Answer (score 1):

Запускайте Service через Application:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
    }
}
```